# Save custom imageview bitmap on buttonclik()

Tags: android, imageview, save

I have created image view with custom shape using 
[siyamed/android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)
Now i want to save the image on SD card with shape.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As the custom view is just an ImageView, try adding something like this to your buttons on click event to save the image as a bitmap;

```
ImageView imageViewCustom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_to_save);
try {
   imageViewCustom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ACustomShapeFolder/file1234.jpg"));
   Bitmap bitmap = imageViewCustom.getDrawingCache();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps!